# How do I tell if I poured a stout correctly?

Tags: stout, serving

What do I need to be paying attention to when I pour a stout and how do I tell if I got it right? Usually this applies to either "regular" stouts or chocolate stouts.

Comment: This varies wildly on the type of beer being poured

Comment: @TomMedley I made it specific to stouts. Is it answerable now?

Comment: Yes, but Guinness is a special case.

Comment: With Guinness, if you can see a clover on top, then you know you've got it right.

Comment: Non-answer: none of the beer landed on the table or down your shirt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like most beers, the main thing is the height of the foam on top of the beer.  It's largely a matter of personal preference; the only considerations I'm aware of are:

- Bottle-fermented beers should be poured slowly and all in one go to prevent yeast from going into the glass (and, to that end, leave half a finger of beer in the bottle).
- Unless it's an unfiltered wheat beer, in which case the yeast is meant to go in the glass.  Also, hefeweizens like this should go for a little larger head than normal (2-2.5 fingers).
- Or if it's a nitrogenated beer (Eg, Guinness with a widget), you should simply [upend the can or bottle into the glass](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNCaV3e9BEg&feature=youtu.be)
- Otherwise, most people aim for about 1 finger-width of foam.  As long as you have at least some head and it doesn't overflow the glass, you're pouring fine.

Comment: Unless you want it to overflow the glass so you can scrape it off with one of those beer-scraper-offer things. I usually go for 2 cm to 2.5 cm of head (foam), which is about one thumb width for me.

Comment: [Notable exception.](http://youtu.be/yNCaV3e9BEg)

Comment: Good call; edited to add nitro beers

Comment: RIP Guinness widget (at least, in the USA)... we'll miss you always.